# How to mock CSS.escape for Jest?

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I've been trying different ways. `CSS.escape as jest.Mock`, or `spyOn`. Nothing has worked, any ideas?

Comment: What did you try? What did not work? Please, check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: If you provide some examples you have tried and what didn't work, it would be easier to provide a feedback